# Cannot communicate back to server from client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Here is my Server class, along with Admin/Client...  The admin can recieve the initial message from the server, but cannot respond back to the server. The Server Socket is created, and when the admin connects to the Server, The Server's message is recieved and printed.  Although once the Server's menu printout("1. Login, etc...").  I cannot enter an option via the console.  It seems to be in a deadlock as soon as the admin prints out the menu sent from the server.

```
/**
   A server that executes the Simple Bank Access Protocol.
*/
public class BankServer extends Thread {  

private Socket sAdmin;
private Scanner inServer;
private PrintWriter outServer;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Bank bank = new Bank(10);
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);
    System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
    Thread admin = new BankServer();
    admin.start();
    while (true) {
        Socket s = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected.");
        BankService service = new BankService(s, bank);
        Thread t = new Thread(service);
        t.start();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void run() {
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8889);
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for admin to connect...");
            while (true) {
                sAdmin = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Admin connected.");
                InputStream instream = sAdmin.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outstream = sAdmin.getOutputStream();
                inServer = new Scanner(instream);
                outServer = new PrintWriter(outstream);
                outServer.print(...+"1. Login\n"+etc...);
                outServer.flush();
                findCommand();
            }
        } finally {
            sAdmin.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void findCommand() throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        if (!inServer.hasNext()) {
            return;
        }
        String command = inServer.next();
        String chosenCommand;
        switch (command) {
            case "1":
                chosenCommand = "LOGIN";
                runCommand(chosenCommand);
                break;
            case "2":
            etc...
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

Ive removed the runCommand method and some fields that don't cause problems to allow for an easier read.

Here is the the admin class.  It will output the options sent from the server, but will not exit the loop of outputing the intial message, and allow me to enter a choice.

```
public class BankAdmin {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket inAdmin = new Socket("localhost", 8889);
    InputStream instream = inAdmin.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outstream = inAdmin.getOutputStream();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
    PrintWriter adminOut = new PrintWriter(outstream);
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        if (!in.hasNextLine()) {
            String command = console.next();
            System.out.println("Sending: " + command);
            adminOut.print("command");
            adminOut.flush();
        } else {
            String response = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: too much code, too wide a problem. Please consider reducing your code and making your problem more specific.

Comment: removed a method, to hopefully make it more simple to read.

Comment: `but cannot respond back to the server` How do you know? Do you get an error? Does it send but the client never receives?

Comment: An error? Maybe a stack trace?

Comment: no the message from the server sends, and the admin/client prints out what the server was sent... but the admin/client cannot enter a choice from the console, to send back to server

Comment: Sorry one of my first posts, I suppose i should reclarify... not having an error, but a logical/deadlock.

Comment: Does it print Sending when you enter at the console?

Comment: Rethink please. It has a lot of code and no indication of what you are trying to do. Please be more specific.

Comment: No, it does not, that is where the deadlock is happening.

Comment: I have reduced the code, to show what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, the JavaDoc on Scanner.hasNextLine() says that it may block while waiting for input. (I'm Still trying to pinpoint the problem)

Comment: Ive attempted to use Scanner.hasNext() and had the same problem.

Comment: ^ which says the same in javadoc. Hmmm

Comment: Just pinpointed the problem. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening:

After the server sends the menu to the client, the client becomes stuck in `in.hasNextLine()`. This is because the `in.hasNextLine()` will block (pause) for input, waiting for a new line (otherwise, it cannot determine whether there will be a next line). To fix this problem, you must use threads, with one waiting for input while the other reads from the console.

For more information, see the [Javadoc on `Scanner.hasNextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--)

Comment: hmm, would it best if I use another thread with my admin?  Or possible read the server input with something other than hasNextLine()?

Comment: Use a thread. Because you can't tell whether the server's gonna send a new line until it does (Java programs are really bad at predicting the future). And it's not just Scanner